# $_SESSION Help How To Use It In One Page? (With Redirect?)

Tags: php, wordpress

I wonder if the following is possible?
My website have a secret link (website.com/?secret=yes) I wanted to make the url look (website.com) after they have entered + show them the special content because they are from the secret link.

I thought about something like this possibly can work? 
1. User Navigate to (website.com/?secret=yes) create a $_SESSION and make it true + Instant navigate to website.com
2. Checks to see if $_SESSION = true if true show the special content?

I have the the following code:

```
<?php $secret = isset( $_GET[ 'secret' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'secret' ] ) : false; ?>

<?php if( 'yes' === $secret ) : ?>
    <div>
        <p>My secret content</p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If it was possible to make use of this + $_SESSION or if you have any ideas? I don't really know how $_SESSION works but i read in php.net about it and i think it's possible?

Thank you!

p.s I use wordpress.

Comment: Yes, that's how sessions can be used. What about the [manual section on session usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) did you have trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this inside of your index.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['secret']) && $_GET['secret'] === 'yes') {
    $_SESSION['secret'] = true;
    header('Location: www.website.com');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['secret']) && $_SESSION['secret'] === true) {
    //Yay!  Display secret content
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten your code to work without a redirect at all. The secret sections can exist in the same page as the landing page, or in different pages. I've also modified the logic so that it will not "forget" the secret status if they come back to the landing page without "?secret=yes" in the URL. I've also updated the code with some basic Javascript that will allow you to remove the "?secret=yes" from the URL without redirecting.

This code would go in any landing page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['secret']) && 'yes' === $_GET[ 'secret' ])
{
    $_SESSION['secret'] = true;
}
?>
```

This code would go in the head section of your page, or the body section if you can't access the head.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['secret']) && 'yes' === $_GET[ 'secret' ])
{
    echo '<script>history.pushState({},"","http://yourdomain.com/pageinurl/");</script>';
}
?>
```

This code would go on any page with secret code:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['secret']) && true === $_SESSION['secret']) { ?>
    <div>
        <p>My secret content</p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Without a redirect should be even better, but I don't seem to understand how can this work? If i would like to give some one the special link (website.com/?secret=yes) he visits it and this code will remove the ?secret=yes from the url address bar?

Comment: I updated my code again. This will allow you to remove "?secret=yes" from the URL without redirecting. Sorry for the late reply.